# How to detect css pseudo :empty in older browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, html5boilerplate

I would like to clear the background of some legend controls whenever they are empty, but my application targets IE7 and above.

I've been researching this, and :empty cuts it for me, but it is only for IE9+.

So I would have to simulate my css thru javascript, and I have below code:

```
   if ($('html').hasClass('lt-ie9')) {
        $("legend:empty,h3:empty")
            .css("background-color", "transparent")
            .height(16); // make equal to newstyles.css
    }
```

I'm using Modernizr and Html5Boilerplate.

So this code seems to work ok, but in IE9 standard mode, I still get the lt-ie9 class, that comes from this extract:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!--<![endif]-->
<HEAD>
```

So my question is:
1. why IE9 still has that tag?
2. is there a way to detect this thru Modernizr?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using jquery and letting it handle the browser differences, e.g. http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: thats exactly what I'm using however, I'm trying to not apply the jquery if the browser can handle it already

Comment: This might help you out... http://snipplr.com/view/9896/

Comment: too fragile since lang may work in IE8+, thanks for the input